# SVN pre-commit script to check for mkdir

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

I wrote the following pre-commit script for SVN to validate that a user has submitted the minimum amount of information on a file commit. However, when trying to add/delete a directory, now it is failing. I know why it's failing obviously, I just didn't realize the pre-commit script was called on every action. How do I filter for the action being performed? Can I do that with **svn log** or do I need to use something else?

```
<?php
define('SVNLOOK', "\"C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server\svnlook.exe\"");
define('NOTEXT', 1000);
define('NOPATTERNMATCH', 1001);
define('ERRORPROCESSING', 9999);

$repo_path = $argv[1];
$transaction = $argv[2];
$tracking_regex_pattern = "/\b(?:bug|issue|ter)\s*[#]{0,1}(\d+)\b/i";

exec(SVNLOOK . " log $repo_path -t$transaction", $revisions);

//loop through transaction message line by line for validation
$validation_passed = (bool) false;
$has_text = (bool) false;
foreach($revisions as $change_line){
  $change_line = trim($change_line);
  if (!empty($change_line)){
    $has_text = true;
    if (preg_match($tracking_regex_pattern, $change_line)) {
        $validation_passed = true;
    }
  }
}

if(!$validation_passed){
  switch($has_text) {
    case true:
      throwError(NOPATTERNMATCH, $revisions);
      break;
    case false:
      throwError(NOTEXT, $revisions);      
      break;
    default:
      throwError(ERRORPROCESSING, $revisions);
      break;
  }   
}else{
  exit(0);
}

function throwError($error_code, $revisions){
  $fp = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, "********** (Error Code: $error_code) **********\n");
  foreach($revisions as $change_line) {
    fwrite($fp, $change_line."\n"); 
  }
  fclose($fp); 
  exit($error_code);  
}
?>
```

How do I test for what svn command is being exectued in the current transaction? Basically I only want the validation to run on a **svn commit** and not a copy, mkdir, etc...

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:** I probably should have clarified with the original post, I am using TortoiseSVN's Create Folder... to do this. Maybe TortoiseSVN is doing some kind of commit operation?

Comment: Call me crazy, but if it's a `pre-commit` hook, shouldn't it *always* be a `commit` operation ... ?

Comment: that was my first thought too... Although, I can see why it would be called on a svn copy too. I'm not in a location I can actually check this however. :(. The doc does say it is **ONLY** called just before a  commit transaction is evaluated to a real revision.

Comment: @silky & Dan - those were my exact thoughts when developing the pre-commit script, but it is in fact happening :(

Comment: hey guys, just to clarify this is the closest description of why post-commit fires "The pre-commit hook is invoked before a Subversion txn is # committed". Since a mkdir command is a transaction like anything else, it fires the pre-commit script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a great answer for you, but...

Maybe you can use `svnlook changed --copy-info` to help a bit. Using that, you can tell if an item was copied from somewhere. If all items are copied, then it *may* be safe to assume this from an `svn copy` instruction. Likewise, if you checking the items returned, you should be able to determine if it was from adding or deleting a directory as well (since it will just be a single directory item being added or deleted.)

Hope it helps somewhat...

Comment: Dan, thanks for the suggestion. While not as straight forward a solution as I would like, it worked very well. I just have to check the changed info for 'A' and see that the addition ends in a "/" which is the only indicator that it is a directory and not a file.